# Does Google Cloud Search (cloudsearch.google.com) natively search chat.google for GSuite users?

Tags: google-workspace

Does Google Cloud Search (cloudsearch.google.com) natively search chat.google for GSuite users?

Google Cloud Search offers to search an array of 3rd party data sources, and does a nice job searching Mail, Drive, Sites, etc. but seemingly **not** Google Chat.  This is agonizing as my company has gotten into the habit of putting most of our important updates and technical info in chat.  I'm trying to unify everything that needs searching within the context of Google Cloud Search.

Can Google Chat be made Google Cloud Search-able with use of a data source connector?  https://support.google.com/a/answer/7056471?hl=en&ref_topic=7056075

Answer (score 0):

This might not be easy to develop if the chat data is treated as third party, because this option is only for org with larger than 500 accounts:

> Your organization needs at least 500 licenses and a Cloud Search certified partner for trials and deployment of third-party data indexing.
> (https://support.google.com/a/answer/11180370?hl=en)

And third party indexing seems to be required to use data sources